# compare_exchange_weak() compile error?

Tags: c++, c++11, atomic

My code looks like this:

```
void C::addB(std::atomic<B>& b)
{

    B* b2 = b.load();
    B newValue = B();

    bool result = b.compare_exchange_weak(b2, newValue, std::memory_order_relaxed, std::memory_order_release);

}
```

and the compiler keeps complaining that the signature does not match a three-member overloaded form of compare_exchaneg_weak:

`note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 4 provided`

Comment: Filling in the blanks and changing the type of `b2` to `B`, [this compiles correctly](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a5456b5fa5fe1bd2). Perhaps a problem with your standard library implementation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code gives me rather more error messages than the fragment you've posted. The most relevant are

```
error: cannot convert ‘B’ to ‘B*’ in initialisation
note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘B*’ to ‘B&’
```

indicating that you're declaring a pointer when you want an object:

```
B b2 = b.load();
```

Answer (score 0):

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/compare_exchange

Refer the prototypes from above URL and pass parameters accordingly.

Comment: It's "refer _to_ the...".

Comment: How does this answer the question? What is the problem with the code above?